# An obtuse triangle revolving around its side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

"We're given a triangle $ABC$, with side $AC = 5$, $\angle CAB = 30^\circ, \angle ACB=45^\circ$. The triangle revolves around side $AC$. Find the surface area of the resulting figure."

I've solved these kinds of problems with right triangles before, but I can't seem to grasp what the result of revolving an obtuse triangle is.

Here's the given picture:

[image]

The picture is kind of confusing to me. From what I understand, the radius of the circle would be the side $OC = OB$. I can find the sides of the triangle using the Law of Sines, but the main problem is i'm not understanding the picture.

Comment: It's two cones, one of revolting $AB$ related to $AC$ and the other of revolting $BC$.

Comment: $\sin 30^{\circ}=\frac{OB}{5},$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you have done similar problems with right triangles. Well, then you can break the given obtuse triangle into two right triangles $\Delta ABO$ and $\Delta CBO$ and finally add the areas (curved surface areas) of the two cones which you get after revolving these two right triangles.

*Solution*- By Sine rule we get, $AB=\frac {5\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}+1}$ and $CB=\frac {10}{\sqrt{3}+1}.$We can also find $AO$ and $CO$ as they are equal to $AB\cos (30)$ and $CB\cos (45) $respectively. $$$$
Total area=area due to $\Delta ABO$ + area due to $\Delta CBO$=$\pi(AO)(AB)+\pi(CO)(CB)$$$$$
Since all the values are Known we can find the total area.

Comment: For some reason I've been looking at this picture all wrong. I've understood now that it's just cones facing opposite ways. Thanks for your effort.